# DC barrel jack datasheet dimensions!

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, dc, eaglecad

[image]

I am using pj-102ah dc barrel jack. I am not sure if this is a mistake in the dimensions, or you can correct me if I am wrong. the top left red circle shows the the length of the three pins which is 1mm, while the bottom red circle shows the length X width which is 1mm X 1.6mm. How come the width is more than the length, and it seems wrong even from the real picture of the jack.

[image]

I updated the footprint as shown in the picture above, where the white squares represent the drills for the pins.

Comment: pin width: 1mm & thickness:?, hole width: 1.6mm & thickness: 1mm

Comment: @WesleyLee : ok, it make sense.

Comment: If your PCB manufacturer doesn't support rectangular cutouts on this scale, you should start with 1.60mm *diameter* round holes, then check fit and alignment requirements for later board revisions.

Comment: @user2943160 : I updated the my question, is that what you mean ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanElshafiey I was just giving unsolicited, related advice since a lot of PCB manufacturers don't support square cutouts. Not looking too closely, but your footprint looks reasonable.

Comment: The pad should extend all the way to the hole's edge.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : So you suggest to decrease the drill size until the pad touches the squares ?

Comment: No, leave the drill the same. Just decrease the inner diameter of the pad.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams : Yes we are talking about the same thing. by drill size I mean the drill of the pad it self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks correct to me. But I can see the reason for the confusion. The PCB layout diagram should have been rotated 180 degrees so it would be more obvious.

The 1mm width of the flat pins would fit with plenty of clearance against the 1.6 mm length of the rectangular hole. The thickness of the pin (not specified) will clear the 1mm hole width.

A 1.6mm round hole should meet the spirit of the spec. Would just need more solder than a rectangular hole.